# iPhone 6: Mobile data activation when on international roaming

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

I am travelling to a different country. I'll be turning on my iPhone only after landing in the visiting country.

I'll be turning off my iPhone before I leave my country and will be turning it on after landing at the destination airport.

I have disabled mobile data and background app refresh in Setting app, as I am concerned about Mobile data consumption and charges when on international roaming.

My SIM card service provider says that the roaming will get activated automatically when I turn on the phone in the destination country.

My question is, will this also automatically enable the mobile data and/or background app refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the mobile data won't turn on automatically (without your manual intervention) when you turn on the mobile.